# How can I configure outer and inner PFSense boxes to allow specific traffic to pass, and so devices can ping each other?

Tags: firewall, routing, pfsense

I have the following infrastructure currently set up, with colors for what I would like to achieve:
[image]

The outer pfsense (EDGE) is currently providing a DMZ to the public and OpenVPN to our road warriors on WAN and WAN1.

Our office devices and some appliance operate inside EDGE and have access to WAN, and some appliance have access to WAN1.

The inner pfsense (INNER1) provide access to EDGE from backoffice devices that need internet connectivity, archive and secure enclave cannot talk out. Ldap is meant to provide authorization and accounting for both network and other internal services.

My question is, how can I make sure that office devices and road warriors have access to backoffice devices from both IP and FDQN? And at the same time, how can I make sure that LDAP is reached from both sides of INNER1 so staff can log on to the network?

I can add that I am fairly new to PFSense, and the other guy has left the company.